# Unable to locate popup with Chrome in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, popup, selenium-chromedriver

Before marking this as duplicate, please read the below points, as i have tried all the possible solutions given :

1. Tried switching to alert and accepting it & dismissing it. It gets stuck to the accept statement.
2. Tried sending the ENTER/RETURN key to the popup. Nothing happens
3. Tried sending ENTER/RETURN key to the window. Nothing happens
4. Tried printing browser url without switching to alert. Throws an exception of unexpectedalertpresentexception.
5. Tried printing the text of the alert. Returns None.
6. Caught the exception and tried printing the alert_text, returns none. Tried printing msg, returns the popup text.

Code Below:

```
    browser.get("https://www.cnm.att.com/emfe/QNCreateTicket?reportTbl=0&tblValue=DHEC297003811&stateCodeValue=&serviceidtypeValue=&trunkgrpandmessageValue=&testFocusControlID1=idfield1&tblCktValue=DHEC297003811&searchStringForASE=%25DHEC297003811%25&oorInd=null&ASEState=null&isASE_ADEinEMDB=&isASE_ADEinEMDBNotProvisioned=&aseflow=&adeflow=&isASEinEBTA=&searchStringForEditForASE=S%3A2%3ADHEC297003811&button=&clci=&qnfromscreen=quick+navigate&phone=&isProvForTesting=1&isProvForCCA=1&isProvForIP=0&isProvForPhone=1&fromtransporttfn=yes&transporttfn=&circuit_format=&state=&ccid=&cac=&isValidPhoneForUser=&isPOTSDataFound=&localPhoneInd=&circuitId=")
Submit_Ticket = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bottomsec"]/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a/img')
Submit_Ticket.click()

time.sleep(3)


    try:
        print browser.title
    except UnexpectedAlertPresentException as e:
        print "exception "+repr(e)
        print "msg"+e.msg
        print browser.current_window_handle
        b = browser.switch_to.window(browser.current_window_handle)
        print b
        b.send_keys(Keys.RETURN,Keys.ENTER)
```

Output:

```
    exception UnexpectedAlertPresentException()
msgunexpected alert open: {Alert text : Before submitting this ticket, you must select the following fields:

 Trouble Type
 Outage Condition
Do you have Power to your Equipment
Authorize Testing
Service Impact}
  (Session info: chrome=52.0.2743.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86)
CDwindow-be1b9858-ddb0-4470-9c11-5f1420a94c82
None

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\alert checking.py", line 72, in <module>
    b.send_keys(Keys.RETURN,Keys.ENTER)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

[image: Popup Alert]

When i click on the popup only then the code executes further.

[image: Submit Element]

Comment: try once using `WebDriverWait` as : `WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(expected_conditions.alert_is_present()).accept()`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Tried that, IDE got stuck at the popup. Nothing happened. :(

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by upgrading the Chrome Driver to version 2.22, earlier it was 2.21 which is buggy in handling javascript popups.